# PHP Scandir returns extra periods

Tags: php, scandir

So I am trying to build a script that scans a directory and returns random images to be used as backgrounds.

The php looks like this:

```
$dir = "views/img/bg/";
$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    $files[] = $filename;
}

$random_key = array_rand($files, 1);

$random = $files[$random_key];
```

Then I am just using some simple jquery to attach the images as backgrounds:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("body").css( "background" , "url(http://'.$url_root.'/views/img/bg/'.$random.'), center center" );

});
</script>
```

Everything works fine but the array of all the images in the background folder seems to be returning stuff like '.' or '..' instead of image names every once in a while. Im not sure what is going on - any ideas?

Comment: Professional-grade advice: [php RecursiveDirectoryIterator: how to exclude directory paths with a dot and double dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19724579/2943403)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'.' and '..' are returned for current and parent directory. You can filter them:

```
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    if ($filename != '.' && $filename != '..')    
        $files[] = $filename;
}
```

Comment: if condition should be like this `if ($filename != '.' && $filename != '..')` other wise .. will be added in the $files array

Comment: so the single dot is the current directory and the two dots are the parent directory?

Answer (score 7):

Use `glob()` so you can filter the files.

```
$files = glob('views/img/bg/*.jpg');
$random = $files[array_rand($files)];
```

Since you're specifying `*.jpg`, `$files` contains only JPG files and you don't need to remove the `.` and `..` items.

Comment: Best solution for me, too. I can filter for specific file extensions in the same step. Note that the filename string comes with the directory path.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use regex? That way it captures any amount of periods. (i.e. ".", "..", "..." etc..)

```
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
        if(!preg_match('/^\.*$/',$filename)){
            $files[] = $filename;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dh = opendir("c:\");
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    if ($filename != '.' && $filename != '..')    
       $files[] = $filename;
}
```