# php RecursiveDirectoryIterator: how to exclude directory paths with a dot and double dots?

Tags: php, iterator, spl

`RecursiveDirectoryIterator` seems to give me two different results from my localhost and live server,

```
define ('WEBSITE_DOCROOT', str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)).'/');

print_r(WEBSITE_DOCROOT);

// List all the class directories in the array.
$main_directories = array(
    'core/model/',
    'core/helper/',
    'core/ext/'
);

// Set other vars and arrays.
$sub_directories = array();

// List any sub dirs in the main dirs above and store them in an array.
foreach($main_directories as $path_directory)
{
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator
    (
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(WEBSITE_DOCROOT.$path_directory), // Must use absolute path to get the files when ajax is used.
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    );

    foreach ($iterator as $fileObject) 
    {
        if ($fileObject->isDir()) 
        {
            //if($fileObject->isDir() === '.' || $fileObject->isDir() === '..') {continue;} 

            // Must trim off the WEBSITE_DOCROOT. 
            $sub_directories[] = preg_replace('~.*?(?=core|local)~i', '', str_replace('\\', '/', $fileObject->getPathname())) .'/';
        }
    }
}

// Mearge the main dirs with any sub dirs in them.
$merged_directories = array_merge($main_directories,$sub_directories);
print_r($merged_directories);
```

localhost,

```
(
    [0] => core/model/
    [1] => core/helper/
    [2] => core/ext/
)
```

live server,

```
(
    [0] => core/model/
    [1] => core/helper/
    [2] => core/ext/
    [3] => core/model/./
    [4] => core/model/../
    [5] => core/helper/./
    [6] => core/helper/../
    [7] => core/ext/./
    [8] => core/ext/../
)
```

So, how can I exclude the directory paths with **a dot and double dots**?

**EDIT:**

Live server - PHP version 5.3.27
Localhost - PHP version 5.5

Answer (score 30):

Try with :

```
new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(WEBSITE_DOCROOT.$path_directory, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php

Comment: Great! I was looking for the same thing, I was excluding them by hand (if dot/dotdot continue)

Comment: Then I guess we'll need more information about your server, the version of PHP you are running, etc. (update your question consequently)

Comment: php.net states PHP 5 >= 5.3.0. I tried with PHP 5.3.26 and it works. Could you may be try again? :/

Comment: it works - avoids dots, problems may be in other places of code (I am trying to zip a dir recursively - but it is other topic)